# Random numbers and if statements

Tags: random-numbers

I want to produce a random number and with this check an if statement.
But it does not work. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[first=0, last=1]{lcg}
\newcommand{\random}{\rand\arabic{rand}}
\begin{document}

\def\var{\random}

\ifnum\var=1
We have a one.
\fi

\ifnum\var=0
We have a zero.
\fi

\end{document}`
```

I thought that the reason might be that the variable \var is not of the same type as 0 or 1.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

`\rand` is not “expandable”. It is an instruction for setting a counter, namely `rand` to some value.

Thus `\ifnum` doesn't find just a number, but a set of instructions to produce one.

You can avoid the issue by using an indirect method:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[first=0, last=1]{lcg}

\newcommand{\newrandomvar}[1]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{}% be sure the name is not taken
  \rand
  \edef#1{\arabic{rand}}% note \edef to end up with the actual value
}

\begin{document}

\newrandomvar{\var}

\ifnum\var=1
We have a one.
\fi

\ifnum\var=0
We have a zero.
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

A “more modern” version.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newrandomvar}{m}
 {
  \tl_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \int_rand:nn { 0 } { 1 } }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\vartest}{mmm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 0 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newrandomvar{\var}

\ifnum\var=1
We have a one.
\fi

\ifnum\var=0
We have a zero.
\fi

We have a \vartest{\var}{zero}{one}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps link to the recent `\Make...case` question, which was also about (non)expansion of macros by `\ifx`

Comment: @JosephWright The two are related by unexpandability, but there are greater differences: `\ifnum` performs macro expansion, contrary to `\ifx`.

Answer (score 1):

A "more modern" version should look like this:

```
\ifcase \pdfuniformdeviate2 We have zero\or We have one\fi
```

The pdfTeX primitive `\pdfuniformdeviate` and TeX primitive `\ifcase` are used here.

The `\pdfuniformdeviate <number>` expands to a random number from `0` to `<number>-1`.

Comment: There are a few issues with `\pdfuniformdeviate`, which can be massaged out: see https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/l3fp-random.dtx

Comment: Try it with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: I am currently working with LuaTeX and I don't see any difference or problems. The primitives `\pdfuniformdeviate`, `\pdfrandomseed` etc. work exactly as described in pdfTeX manual.